# checkbox list check only limited items

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a list of check boxes and I want to have an upper limit for you many you can check. 
Here is what i have done.

```
            int numSelected = 0;
            foreach (ListItem li in chkMultiBrand.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    numSelected = numSelected + 1;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < chkMultiBrand.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (numSelected >= Convert.ToInt32(objLimit.UPPERLIMIT))
                {
                    chkMultiBrand.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's the question? What happens with the code you have?

Comment: the problem is when chkMultiBrand.Items[i].Selected = false;
is get all the other checkboxes are also getting unchecked...

Comment: i wants only beyond this limit the user can not be checkd

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: selected index changed of checkboxlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume if the max number has been exceeded you want to *uncheck* the last box that was checked so this should work

```
public void chk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int numSelected = 0;
     foreach (ListItem li in chkMultiBrand.Items)
     {
         if (li.Selected)
         {
             numSelected = numSelected + 1;
         }
     }
     if (numSelected >= Convert.ToInt32(objLimit.UPPERLIMIT))
     {
          string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
          int index = control.Length - 1;
          ListItem lastChecked = (ListItem) chkMultiBrand.Items[Int32.Parse(control[index])];
          lastChecked.Selected = false;
     }
 }
```

Although I would possibly try to do this client side if possible - something like this http://jsfiddle.net/CXfgS/2/

Answer (score 0):

If Im reading this correctly as your code stands what yours doing is

1. Counting the number of checked boxes in the whole list
2. If the number from the prvious count is greater than the max allowed set everything to false

You need to combine the loops - this isn't perfect as it doesn't track the order in which the items are selected so only the first X number of checkboxes will remain checked and any subsequent items will be unselected.

```
        int numSelected = 0;
        foreach (ListItem li in chkMultiBrand.Items)
        {
            if (numSelected >= Convert.ToInt32(objLimit.UPPERLIMIT))
            {
                li.Selected = false;
            }
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                numSelected = numSelected + 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: i want to track the order also in which the items are selected.